# When can you float?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

Can you float elements that are positioned in any way? Or do floated elements have to be static? For example, is it possible to float elements which are positioned relatively?

Comment: Why you don't try when you can use float?

Answer (score 1):

Float and position are two different things, although they do influence each other. Floats have zero impact on elements which are positioned absolutely or fixed. Floats only have an impact on elements which are positioned statically (Default) or relatively.

Answer (score 1):

Much of this is dictated by [a single subsection within the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). In particular if you're only concerned about how the `position` property interacts with the `float` property, then that subsection says that

1. you cannot float an element that is absolutely positioned (either `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`), but
2. you *can* float an element that is either relatively positioned or static (i.e. non-positioned).

In both cases, the `position` property will take effect as normal, but the `float` property will not have any effect on an absolutely positioned element. This means that an absolutely positioned element will remain in its absolute position, and a relatively positioned element can still be shifted relative to where it would originally have been located, taking the `float` property into account (as well as acting as a containing block for other positioned elements).